# Do you know syntax to give permission for AWS API Gateway to call a Lambda function?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS Lambda function `juno-feedback` that runs successfully if I TEST it **within** the AWS Lambda console.

But when I try and call it **from API Gateway** all I get back is: `{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}`

@KMo was very helpful with my initial issue but now I've got beyond that, the initial comments are no longer relevant to this question.

I have made a successful Add Permission call from the aws cmdline tool following the instructions the console displays:

`You defined your Lambda function as a stage variable. Please ensure that you have the appropriate Function Policy on all functions you will use. You can do this by running the below AWS CLI command for each function, replacing the stage variable in the function-name parameter with the necessary function name.`

The command I ran:
`aws lambda add-permission    --function-name "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:012345678901:function:juno-openAlertOff:dev"    --source-arn "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:012345678901:ww11ww1w1/*/GET/open/alertOff"    --principal apigateway.amazonaws.com    --statement-id 1aa1111a-1a1a-1111-aa11-1a1111111a1a    --action lambda:InvokeFunction`

and it replies with a success response.

In APIG, under `Stages/dev/Stage Variables` I have Name:Value of functionaAlias:dev

Have I correctly replaced `${stageVariables.functionAlias}` with my stage variable name `dev` ?

Comment: Are you sure you just haven't typed in the wrong url? Did you make sure to include the resource at the end of the url displayed in dashboard in API Gateway? If not you will get the message {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}

Comment: thanks @KMo what format do resource names take?

Comment: @KMo - I'm using the URL generated by APIG. Those URLs do end in my resource https://....execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/open/feedback

Comment: Umm... what ever you named them. In AWS Console -> API Gateway -> Your API Name -> Resources, you'll have a list of all the resources you created. Under Dashboard you'll find "invoke API at:" whatever base path AWS has assigned. You need to call your API using basepath/resource. Also, make sure you have Deployed your API before testing. Might not resolve your issue, but these are common mistakes that produce the missing authentication token error.

Comment: Yes, I've been clicking the link at "Invoke URL:" and trying to call it from a local web browser page. I've also deployed. I have many other APIs that are protected by authentication and these work from my App (when a user is signed in). Now I'm trying to add a APIG resource that is not protected by authentication

Comment: Do you have any resources listed under 'Resources' in the APIG console? Also, I'm assuming that your method is a GET, if not it won't work calling it from a browser.

Comment: Yes, I have over a dozen resources listed Resources. The method is a POST so I've created a form on a local HTML page and submit that. The 'aws' call in my question is replying with an error. could it be a misleadingly worded error message?

Comment: I have one stageVariable defined. Name:Value = functionAlias:dev so I think I can leave ${stageVariables.functionAlias} as it is in my question. But I can't see where Amazon's regex is tripping up.

Comment: So your post would be basepath+(one of your resources)? If you think the issues is between API Gateway and Lambda, have you tested it in API Gateway? Do you get the same response?

Comment: @KMo yes I do. I've found the issue with the regex. I need to replace ${stageVariables.functionAlias} but with what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172522/discussion-between-carl-and-k-mo).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lambda function -> Api Gateway stage variable permission manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639536/lambda-function-api-gateway-stage-variable-permission-manually)