# How to point AWS API gateway stage to specific lambda function alias?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

So as per the AWS documentaion

> Instead of using Amazon Resource Names (ARNs) for Lambda function in
>   event source mappings, you can use an alias ARN. This approach means
>   that you don't need to update your event source mappings when you
>   promote a new version or roll back to a previous version.

I have AWS lambda function `pets` and i have created 2 aliases `dev` and `prod` pointing to different versions of lambda function.

Then in API Gateway i am using this lambda function in `Integration Request`. I have two stages of API, `development` and `production`. I want `development` API stage point to `dev` Lambda alias ARN and `production` needs to point to `prod` alias.

When i select lambda function as `Integration Type` then drop down list shows  whatever display name i have given earlier while creating lambda function..[image]

I am not finding any stage specific configuration for lambda function. Based on my research on SO i have to follow these steps to deploy `development` stage pointing to `dev` alias

1> Go to `Integration Request`
2> Select Lambda function and change it to `pets:dev`
3> Deploy  to `development` stage

Follow the same steps for `production` by changing Lambda function to `pets:prod` before deployment.

This is going to be maintenance nightmare as our lambda function grows. Is there any easier way to do it?

Comment: Are you using IaC tools like cloudformation or terraform? If so I don't think it's a huge pain if you have a unified naming convention.

Comment: I am using AWS console. Not sure about the tools you mentioned but I will look into it

Comment: Generally terraform is better choice for managing you own infrastructure. If your infrastructure needs to be deployed to different aws accounts from you account, cloudformation is better.

Comment: Will IaC allows you to do 1 to 1 mapping between API stages and Lambda Alias?

Comment: Have you looked at [serverless](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/)?

Comment: isn't aws lambda serverless? also your link is too generic doesn't answer my question

Comment: The comments started with IaC tools discussion. Serverless is highly used for deploying AWS Lambda and their API Gateway events with just one Yaml file configuration. I only suggested from IaC tools perspective if you want to avoid doing these via console in production.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found it
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-stage-variables-to-manage-lambda-functions/

Here are the steps I followed:

1. After creating lambda function, create 2 aliases for lambda
   function. `dev` pointing to `$latest` version and `prod` pointing a
   particular version you want to use in prod
2. Then goto API Gateway console ->Integration Request ->Lambda function,  and type
   `pets:${stageVariables.lambdaAlias}` where `pets` is my function name and `lambdaAlias` is the stage variable that we will have to add in each API stage
3. Deploy your API to new API stages `development` and `production`
4. In each API stage add stage variable `lambdaAlias` with value `dev` and `prod` respectively. The stage variable value must match with lambda function's  alias

[image]

Now we don't have to keep changing lambda alias name for each API deployment

Comment: The latest version of their UI doesn't allow a stage variable to be input in the Integrations function name. Does anyone know how this should work now?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to do it through the UI, but it works fine with the aws cli by putting the variables pretty much where you expect. --Doing it that way also shows the proper way to use the UI. You need to manually specify the full ARN, you can't just pick your lambda function name and then append `${stagingVariables.lambdaAlias}`.

Comment: Hi @moswald, are you saying that step 2 of the accept answer where it specifies to put `pets:${stageVariables.lambdaAlias}` in the **Lambda Function** box of the **Integration** will not work? Do we need to specify `arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<account-id>:function:pets:${stageVariables.lambdaAlias}` instead?

Comment: @NeilG - Honestly, I don't know. It's been too long and I don't work on that project anymore.

Comment: Lol, thanks @moswald. I'm getting more and more material from AWS docs on this and still challenged to get any specificity. AWS is really good at not being comprehensive or specific. It's all example based documentation or tutorials or blogs with really simple use cases, and even the *reference* documentation is loosely worded and covers only a sub-set of cases also by example, not by rule! Astonishing really. I'm actually having a meeting with AWS documentation project members about this next week! :-D